# aligning magento top links left and right

Tags: layout, magento-1.9, local.xml, toplinks

I have added additional static links in magento top link beside checkout login etc. 
Default welcome, my account etc links are left aligned, and i want my additional links to be right aligned.

I am wondering how can i just control additional links i mean set of additional links to align right?
 For controlling with css we need some container element for only additionl links, but adding it with xml only create more `li` tags and append it in same ul.

here is my code

```
<default>
<reference name="top.links">
<action method="addLink" translate="label title">
<label>Custom Link 1</label>
<url>http://www.example.com/</url>
<title>Custom Link 1</title>
<prepare/>
<urlParams/> 
<position>101</position>
       <liParams >
       <class>custom_link</class>
       </liParams>
<aParams><![CDATA[target="_blank"]]></aParams>
</action>
</reference>
```

I am wondering how can sorround these links with a div or any container element to which i can apply my css. i Can add class to individual item, but how to add class to the bunch 5 additional links only without touching the postioning of default links
can someone help?

Below is the Snapshot how i want to achieve.
[image: Snapshot of how i would like to achieve]

Comment: "how to add class to the bunch 5 additional links only without touching the postioning of default links" > could you please give an example of the expected/problematic sorting of your top links or a screenshot?

Comment: updated question with snapshot. thank u :-) @AnnaVölkl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about just put a `position:relative` on the outer diff and position them absolute?

If not, you have a problem, because magento doesnt differ between your additional links.

The alternative is to just add your links directly into `page/template/links.phtml`